# WiX Bundle not displaying MSIs in Programs and Features

Tags: wix, uninstallation

I've got new, weird behavior in my bundle installation:  the MSIs -- which used to appear in Programs and Features -- have stopped appearing in Programs and Features (hereafter referred to as P&F).

The behavior that I'd *like* to happen is for the programs that I install as MSIs to appear in P&F, giving the user the chance to uninstall them discretely.

What I've tried/noticed:

- If I install the MSIs without bundling them:
- they appear in P&F, and are able to be uninstalled
- moreover, I can control whether they appear in P&F by setting the ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT property to either 1 (default is 0, meaning "do appear in P*F), that is:
  `<Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1"/>`
- these changes are reflected in the registry.  When examining the key *HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall/{GUID}*, if I set the property to 1 it shows up (it doesn't show up when I set it to 0, but I think that's because defaults don't show up).

However, when I put the MSIs into a Bundle, *bingo-bango-bongo* they disappear from P&F! And, if I check the registry, the *SystemComponent* property is set to 1 for each MSI.

I'm reaching the conclusion that somehow, in my bootstrapper, the *SystemComponent* properties for my MSIs are being set to 1.  But where could these properties be set?  Needless to say, I never set them in my WiX XML (at least, I don't think I do).  I don't have any special UI for the bootstrapper (just a license), and the MSIs themselves install quietly, with no UI.

I'm stuck!  Can anyone shed some light on this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, WiX version 3.10.  Here's the entirety of my Bootstrapper code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
    <Bundle Name="****"
            Version="1.0.5.0"
            Manufacturer="****"
            UpgradeCode="7be91f26-93f8-400c-9eac-e69383454e03"
            IconSourceFile="src\****.ico" DisableModify="yes" DisableRemove="yes"
            AboutUrl="****.com"
            Copyright="Copyright 2017, ****">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="src\****_License.rtf" 
                                                    SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <!-- The two registry serarches provide a variable, what version of .NET is installed on the target machine.  One search
           is for x86, the other for x64. -->
        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                             Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                             Value="Version"
                             Variable="Net452FullVersion"/>
        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                             Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                             Value="Version"
                             Variable="Net452x64FullVersion" 
                             Win64="yes"/>

        <Chain>
            <ExePackage
                Id="Microsoft_dot_Net_4.5.2" 
                Name="Microsoft 4.5.2 Setup"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="yes"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                SourceFile="executables\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" 
                InstallCommand="/q"
                DetectCondition="(Net452FullVersion = &quot;4.5.51209&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Net4x64FullVersion = &quot;4.5.51209&quot;))"
                InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND (NOT (Net452FullVersion = &quot;4.5.51209&quot; OR Net452x64FullVersion = &quot;4.5.51209&quot;))"/>
            <ExePackage Id="Microsoft_Visual_C_plus_plus_Redistributable_2015" 
                        InstallCommand="/q" 
                        SourceFile="executables\vc_redist.x86.exe"/>
            <RollbackBoundary/>                    
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.****.TargetPath)"/>
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.****.TargetPath)"/>
            <ExePackage SourceFile="executables\****.exe" InstallCommand="/S"/>
            <ExePackage SourceFile="executables\****.exe"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MsiPackage/@Visible` attribute controls whether MSI packages are shown in ARP.

Comment: MAJOR face-palm!  Thanks.  That's something that I really, really should not have wasted three hours on (at least I learned stuff about the registry).